# Create new columns from string existance

Tags: r

In a draframe

```
data.frame(stocknum = c(1,2,3), col1 = c("my text here", "another one", "one more final text"))
```

How can detect if the words "text" and "final" exist in every row in column col1 and create new columns with one if the exist in the text and 0 if not

Example output:

```
data.frame(stocknum = c(1,2,3), col1 = c("my text here", "another one", "one more final text"), text = c(1,0,1), final = c(0,0,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(text = +str_detect(col1, 'text'), final = +str_detect(col1, 'final'))
  stocknum                col1 text final
1        1        my text here    1     0
2        2         another one    0     0
3        3 one more final text    1     1
```

Data used:

```
df
  stocknum                col1
1        1        my text here
2        2         another one
3        3 one more final text
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(stocknum = c(1,2,3), col1 = c("my text here", "another one", "one more final text"))
txt <- c("text", "final")
bind_cols(df, map_dfc(txt, ~transmute(df, !!paste0(.x) := +str_detect(df$col1, .x))))

#>   stocknum                col1 text final
#> 1        1        my text here    1     0
#> 2        2         another one    0     0
#> 3        3 one more final text    1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

An option in `base R` with `grepl`

```
df[c('text', 'final')] <- +(sapply(c('text', 'final'), grepl, x= df$col1))
```

-output

```
df
#  stocknum                col1 text final
#1        1        my text here    1     0
#2        2         another one    0     0
#3        3 one more final text    1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only `base R` and `apply()`:

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(stocknum = c(1,2,3), col1 = c("my text here", "another one", "one more final text"))
#Code
df$text <- apply(df['col1'],1,function(x) as.numeric(length(which(grepl('text',x)))>=1))
df$final <- apply(df['col1'],1,function(x) as.numeric(length(which(grepl('final',x)))>=1))
```

Output:

```
df
  stocknum                col1 text final
1        1        my text here    1     0
2        2         another one    0     0
3        3 one more final text    1     1
```